# Mongoose: What is the difference between using ref type or [model schema] when referring another model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, orm

I want to refer to another model (1:N relationships) and I have this code working properly:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

AuthorSchema = require('./Author.js');

var BlogSchema = new Blog({
  ...,
  author: [AuthorSchema]
});
```

What is the difference between this approach, and using reference (such as below:)

```
var BlogSchema = new Blog({
    ...,
    author: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Author'}]
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant to write `new Schema` instead of `new Blog`.

In the first approach, we embed the author info inside the blog like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5e84967e28bc413f14b43fce",
    "title": "blog 1 title",
    "author": [
        {
            "_id": "5e84967e28bc413f14b43fd0",
            "name": "author 1 name"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e84967e28bc413f14b43fcf",
            "name": "author 2 name"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

So when we need a blog and it's authors, we simply query like this without using any populate.

query:

```js
router.get("/blogs/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Blog.findById(req.params.id);
  res.send(result);
});
```

With this approach, when we need to update an author's info, it will be more difficult since they must be updated in all places.

In the reference approach, we only keep the author ids in the author array of blog. So the blog document looks like this:

```
{
    "title": "blog 1 title",
    "author": [
        "5e849753cf11581f683012b4",
        "5e84975bcf11581f683012b5"
    ]
}
```

The referenced sample authors documents in the authors collection:

```
{
    "_id": "5e849753cf11581f683012b4",
    "name": "author 1 name",
    "__v": 0
}

{
    "_id": "5e84975bcf11581f683012b5",
    "name": "author 2 name",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Now if we want to get a blog and it's authors full data, we need to use populate like this:

```js
router.get("/blogs/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Blog.findById(req.params.id).populate("author");
  res.send(result);
});
```

Giving this result:

```
{
    "author": [
        {
            "_id": "5e849753cf11581f683012b4",
            "name": "author 1 name",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e84975bcf11581f683012b5",
            "name": "author 2 name",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5e849792cf11581f683012b6",
    "title": "blog 1 title",
    "__v": 0
}
```

But with this approach, updating author data will be easier and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Using ref type as model schema like this:

```
var BlogSchema = new Blog({
...,
author: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: AuthorSchema }]
```

}

Solves problems in cases where the ref collection does not yet exist in MongoDB.
If you use ref as a string in case where the collection hadn't been created yet,like this:
`var BlogSchema = new Blog({ ..., author: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author'}] }`
you would get an error:
"MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model 'Author'